# Is the subcaption package incompatible with aaai.sty?

Tags: subcaption

A number of packages including `caption` are included in the AAAI formatting requirements as incompatible, and the list is said to be not exhaustive.

Is the `subcaption` package permitted?

I am particularly interested on preparing my submission to follow the instructions of this conference:

http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/icwsm-submit.php

If you open the /AuthorKit16/LaTeX/formatting-instructions-latex.pdf in the Author Kit zip file you will see the list of forbidden packages:

**Incompatible Packages**

The following packages are incompatible with aaai.sty
and/or aaai.bst and must not be used (this list is not exhaus-
tive — there are others as well):

- authblk
- fullpage
- hyperref
- natbib
- geometry
- titlesec
- layout
- caption
- titlesec
- savetrees
- T1 fontenc package (install the CM super fonts
  package instead)

However, the website lists some common latex errors and simply states that:

- 16. If you've used caption.sty so that you can use subcaption, you may
      not use any options.

If the `subcaption` package is not permitted, is there any other way to create a figure that comprises multiple subfigures?

Comment: Can you add a link to the requirements, please?

Comment: I just did, I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` should be good

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using `subfig` without captions is not very clear though, so I think I'd better just stop using `caption` and `subcaption` packages

Comment: The `caption=false` option just avoids loading the `caption` package. You can certainly use subcaptions to the subfigures using the syntax provided by `subfig`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg. I can't up-vote comments, I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: With `geometry`, `hyperref`, `natbib`, `titlesec`, and `caption`/`subcaption` all on the proscribed list of the `aaai` package, one is tempted to ask, "what's going on with the `aaai` package?!

Comment: @Mico I guess all these packages are not really incompatible (in technical terms), they just don't want changes in page size, bibliography, sections, and captions. (And no hyperlinks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the `aaai` and `subcaption` packages technically incompatible? Just try it out, if yes, the `caption` package will give you an "incompatibility" warning and the `subcaption` package an error when adding `\usepackage{subcaption}` to your document.

The content from the AAAI is (at least to me) misleading. On the one hand they clearly say that the `caption` package is incompatible, and this makes the `subcaption` package incompatible, too. But on the other hand they write that it's ok to use the `subcaption` (and `caption`) package as long as you don't specify any options (which would alter the look & feel of the captions).

So it seems to me that the `caption` package is not really incompatible but the AAAI simply does not want any changes to the look & feel of the captions.

I think it's a good idea to ask them for clarification here.

However, if in doubt, use the `subfig` package with option `caption=false`, as already proposed from egreg in the comments.